# Javascript Controller to Apex Controller naming syntax error

Tags: apex, javascript, controller

I am getting an odd bug where capitalizing the first letter of an Apex method that returns a map, causes an error within the javascript controller.

Javascript:

```
var action = component.get("c.OpAddOnCount");
```

Apex Controller:

```
public static Map<String,Integer> OpAddOnCount() {...}
```

When I capitalize the name in both JS and Apex, I get an error. However, if I make the first letter a lowercase 'o' (in both JS and Apex), everything works fine.

I am new to JS, is there an obvious syntax issue that I am unaware of? I want to make sure I don't get hung up on something like this again for so long!

Comment: Yep the case needs to match. Surprised about what you've seen through. Have you treble checked that you have changed both consistently i.e. both to upper case?

Comment: what is the name of the JS function that has the `var action` line? It must be named differently than the Apex Method. Quirky, but it is what it is.

Comment: Yes, I even copied and pasted so I knew I had the cases matching exactly. For some reason is still only works when the "o" is lowercase.

Comment: Name of the JS function is doInit.

Answer (score 2):

While [Salesforce's naming conventions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_naming_conventions.htm) for Apex are optional in general, this isn't the case with Aura-linked server-side controller methods. I suspect this is due to JavaScript convention expectations (and that many IDEs will whinge if uppercase letters start function names that are not constructor functions [and vice versa]).

I can't say that I've seen any documentation on this one, but I certainly hit this same problem myself a year or two back.

Some useful reading [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_vf_tips/lex_dev_lc_vf_tips_apex) as well about parameter naming and the need to avoid name overloading on the client-side.